# MVC3 Read Only Text Box but value must be POSTed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way in MVC3 to make a read-only Text Box where the value is POST'ed back?

I have tried the following (from others on this site):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model.xxxx, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "text-box single-line", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

However the value does not get POST'ed, inspecting it gives NULL.
I used a text box for styling reasons and because I thought it would post back correctly. I have JScript on the page that updates the value, hence why Its important to be able to get back its POST'ed value.

I will start looking at using a DisplayFor and HiddenFor pair but would like to know if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: If the textbox is needed because of the styling, you have two options:  use an additional hidden field, or serialize the whole `form` in JavaScript and use AJAX to POST it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Html specification says that disabled fields should not be submitted therefore you can only use readonly in your situation, where you want to update the value from JS and submit it. readonly with a CSS class that makes it look disabled gives a better UI experience. Alternatively, just use a span plus hidden input.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1

"Disabled controls cannot be successful." and "A successful control is "valid" for submission."

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model.xxxx, new {@class = "text-box single-line", @readonly = "readonly", onfocus = "this.blur()" })
```

Comment: readonly is the Trick. Better use readonly instead of disabled and you don't have to use hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You seemingly have a typo error in @disabled!

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model.xxxx, new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "text-box single-line", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Since the user cannot edit it, your other option is HiddenFor, and you can then submit that value back through your ViewModel

Alternatively, you could disable the TextBox on page load rather than in mark-up and use Javascript or jQuery to enable it again as needed (i.e. Edit button or something)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned (and others), I would use:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Model.xxxx)
```

and

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Model.xxxx).
```